# Saturnian Cloud Cities Series

Tags: discussion, reference

Note: This <s>question</s> post is going to be kept as a catalogue/archive for the questions in my series "Saturnian Cloud Cities". It is going to be updated from time-to-time, to add links to new questions.

[Part 1- Cloud City](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/234062/saturnian-cloud-cities-pt-1-cloud-city)

[Part 2- Ice Harvester Planes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/235907/saturnian-cloud-cities-pt-2-ice-harvester-planes)

[Part 3- Wind Turbine Problems](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/236002/saturnian-cloud-cities-pt-3-wind-turbine-problems?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Part 4- Deploying Cloud-Cities](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/236007/saturnian-cloud-cities-pt-4-how-to-deploy-the-cloud-city?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Part 5- Shielding from Saturnian Weather](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/236765/saturnian-cloud-cities-pt-5-shielding-of-cloud-cities-from-saturnian-weather?rq=1)

[Part 6- Geothermal Cables Vs Stupendously Large Airships](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/237103/saturnian-cloud-cities-pt-6-geothermal-cables-vs-stupendously-large-airships?rq=1)

Comment: Are you open to others building around this idea?

Comment: Yes, I am open to other people as well

Comment: I like this idea. I would recommend, however, that other users who build around or upon your idea submit an answer to this post with their list of questions so that your original intent isn't lost. That way other contributors can include an explanation of what their take on your worldbuilding efforts might be. Cheers!